# Shared variable for all slaves in MPI

Tags: c, mpi

I am not able to find anything related to shared variable or pointer for all the slaves processes in MPI programming on the internet. I am working with a MPI programming in C, I want to create shared variable which is accessible by all the slaves.

Let's say I have a Array Pointer, Now I want that pointer to be accessible to all the slave processes.

Any Lead to resources or any help is really appreciated.

Comment: This is not how MPI and distributed computing works. If you plan to use a single node, OpenMP is a better fit for that. If you need MPI, look at one sided communications while keeping in mind the semantic is a bit counterintuitive and this might not be the fastest option performance wise.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my wrong understanding, I will try to work accordingly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.